# ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Angular 9 deploy to a subdomain for IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, deployment

I have an angular application with .Net Core 3.1 as a backend with Identity. When I deploy the application to IIS to the default Website, bound to the Server's IP Address, then the application can be viewed, I can click the Login and Register links: http://myipaddress/authentication/register and http://myipaddress/authentication/login and all other api calls like http://myipaddress/api/test/showmessage are all working correctly. This is served from C:\Inetpub\vhosts\default\htdocs.
Now I want to deploy the same application on a subdomain: like http://subdomain.domain.com
and is served from: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\subdomain.domain.com
The above mentioned links don't work anymore. The register and login links are just stuck showing the navigation bar and a blank page , and the api call redirects back to the home.

What can I do to deploy this application to that subdomain?